# CORS preflight request returning HTTP 405

Tags: php, http-headers, cors, silex

I am trying to create a RESTful web service and have gotten stuck on implementing PUT requests. I have tried and failed to follow other answers on this site and various articles from Mozilla.

The request is generated from the domain `wwwtest.dev-box` and it's going to `test.dev-box` (basically a front-end app calling the back-end app). Here are the headers I have captured from Live HTTP headers:

```
http://test.dev-box/resource/v1/data/user/1

OPTIONS /resource/v1/data/user/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: test.dev-box
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://wwwtest.dev-box
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 16:15:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
x-powered-by: PHP/5.3.27
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wwwtest.dev-box
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Length: 0
Allow: PUT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm using a framework so everything is routed to web.php, which contains the following code at the top of the page (taken from [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-Side_Access_Control)):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wwwtest.dev-box');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Access Forbidden");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
}
```

Before my code makes the PUT request it sends the CORS preflight OPTIONS request first (as you can see from the capture above). The necessary headers should be attached to the response and tell the requester that PUT is allowed. Unfortunately as you can see from the response headers above it is still returning 405 Method Not Allowed even though PUT is in the response access-control-allow-methods.

This is the .htaccess file for the framework I'm using (Silex):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the answer to be a cross between Apache and framework configuration.

1. For the Apache config you can either put the following into your VirtualHost directive, or in the .htaccess file of the requested domain (if it's in the .htaccess remember to encapsulate with IfModule mod_headers.c tags). Setting the headers on the page that mod_rewrite redirects to does not work:

```
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://wwwtest.dev-box"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"
```

2. For the Silex config, place the following into your application routes. It basically sends an HTTP 200 OK for any OPTIONS request it receives. Code found on the [Silex Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/silex-php/ORRdF7yICao/4pL7rmWZybsJ):

```
    $app->match("{url}", function($url) use ($app) {
        return "OK";
    })->assert('url', '.*')->method("OPTIONS");
```

Both steps need to be completed for the RESTful application to function properly.

Answer (score 3):

The 405 is in reference to the actual preflight/OPTIONS request.  Your server is rejecting the preflight outright as OPTIONS requests in general are not accepted by your server.  You'll need to modify your server configuration to accept OPTIONS requests.  Simply including code in a PHP file may not be enough.  Most likely your web/application server is not aware of this verb and is rejecting the request before it hits your PHP code.

Comment: I have not heard of Apache blocking OPTIONS requests outright in any of the articles I have read. Do you have any information on this, or an idea of how I might configure it?

Comment: Hmm, looking closer, it appears that your PHP code is being executed, since the CORS headers are included on the response.  Most likely something in your PHP code is returning a 405 then.  You'll have to post all of your PHP code.

Comment: Not possible to post code, but I'm using Silex which is a framework based off Symfony2 if that helps. I'm not doing anything with access restriction or modifying headers, etc. Just trying to PUT to a route and get some data back.

Comment: This framework, like most others, is redirecting traffic to a handler using mod_rewrite. Could that be causing any issues? I've posted the .htaccess file contents in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ray, your answer helped me look closer into Apache which led me to find the issue. Cheers!