# Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status of 405

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, get, cors

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:2986/api/SatinalmaSiparisleri/getSatinAlmaSiparisleri',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var trHTML = '';
            var j = 99;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td><span class="' + i + '">' + data[i].stokTanimi+ '</span></td>'
                       +'<tr><td><span>' + data[i].siparisMiktari+ '</span></td>'
                       + '<td><span class="' + j + '">' + data[i].teslimTarihi+ '</span></td>'
                       + '<td><button style="width:100%" data-id="' + i + '" class="onay btn btn-success"> Onay </button></td>'
                       + '<td><input type="text" class="denied form-control" placeholder="Reddetme Sebebi"></input>'
                       + '<td><button style="width:100%" data-id="' + j + '" class="ret btn btn-danger"> Ret </button></td></tr>';
                j++;
            };
            $('#location').append(trHTML);


        },

        error: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
```

When I'm trying to GET request with ajax i'm getting this error
[Console Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxj4T.png)
I'm search a lot of this error on the web but i can't fix this. I was tried to adding these lines web api's web config file

```
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
```

it wasn't help me so i was tried to disabling chrome extensions and it doesn't help me too. Finally i was checked Cors on the project and it's already up to date.

Here it's Network screen
[Network Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdnd6.png)

How can i fix this errors ?

PS: i was checked api with postman it works fine .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS preflight request returning HTTP 405](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409105/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-405)

Comment: thanks ur help but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are creating the web api.

I had the same problem two days ago but i solved it.

When you're creating the web api application, by default it creates the ValuesController.

Put the below code in it:

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
        {
            return new List<Customer> {
           new Customer(){CustomerId=1,CustomerName="Name1"},
             new Customer(){CustomerId=2,CustomerName="Name2"},
            };
        }


    }
```

and now add one customer class like below.

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
```

And now run the application. Now just change the URL to localhost:ursport/api/values. You got the xml file. It is your data file.

Now create the another application for acessing the data from webapi.
and add the following code.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            ;
            $.ajax({
                //url: 'http://192.168.1.105:2143/api/values',
                url: 'public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
',


                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',            
                success: function (data) {                

                    alert(data[0].CustomerName);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

I hope this is useful. Let me know if you have any doubts.
Make sure the web api application is running while running the client application.

Comment: i solved it too thanks for answer . I jus deleted these lines
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,

Comment: hi @HarunKARATAŞ ,if  it is useful,accept answer by upvoting my answer.