# ionic 2 post request not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using below code for post method request in ionic 2.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');

let body = new FormData();
body.append('UserName', 'sp');
body.append('password', 's');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

this.http
    .post('http://192.168.1.9:8080/api/Restaurant/Login', body, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("Response is ::::::",data);
        },
          err => {
          console.log("ERROR!::::: ", err);
        }
    );
```

Above http://192.168.1.9:8080/api/Restaurant/Login is my local URL. With this URL i am able to get request / response from iOS simulator and postman but not from ionic 2 project.

I am getting error as per attached screenshot.

[image]

Server side we added below CORS headers.

```
<httpprotocol>
    <customheaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customheaders>
</httpprotocol>
```

Can any one help where i am wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');` are server side headers.. you dont need to set in ionic app

Comment: @suraj In server side these all headers are added. If i remove these headers from ionic app, then also it is not working.

Comment: Try this `let body = {
   UserName: 'sp',
   password: 's',
  };`

Comment: @hrdkisback Not working with this body.

Comment: how are you receiving in server side? as json?

Comment: @suraj yes in json format

Comment: is this with ionic serve? looks like a CORS issue.. your serverside CORS headers may not be set correctly...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409105/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-405

Comment: @suraj In my mac i added CORS (cross origin resource sharing) addon and make on it. 

But how i have to set CORS from server side. Can you explain me?

Comment: that depends on your serverside technology.. you will have to add those details

Comment: In server side we are using .net technology for api. So that in .net technology at server i have to add CORS?

Comment: you have to add the required headers correctly..yes

Comment: As per you told me we have added above CORS headers to server. Please visit updated question.

Comment: @codeMonkey This API can be calling in LAN only. This will not be live API so i can't call in ios device.

Answer (score 1):

On your sever side, do you have WebSecurity configured? My experience with angular is that it sends a pre-flight OPTIONS request before the actual request is sent, if your sever doesn't support OPTIONS requests then it will reject it.
I'm not sure if this will help you as it's set in Spring.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.....

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/user").permitAll()
        ...
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll() //This allows options requests
        ...

}
```

All the best! Hope you can succeed :)
Happy coding