# Jquery + html5 : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on simple phonagap application. I am trying to run index.html directly on chrome browser.All other REST calls are working properly so I can fetch data. But in one REST call I am getting following error:

```
Failed to load http://example.com/stack/api/order_food: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.
```

I have found many thread on forum but unfortunately nothing is worked for me. I have following meta tag in my index.html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Also following is my ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
        "url": "http://example.com/stack/api/order_food",
        "type": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "data": form,
        success: function (resultData) {
            if(!resultData)
            {
                alert("Failed to get result data");
                return;
            }            
            var res = JSON.parse(resultData);
            if(res.status == "success")
            {
                alert("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409105/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-405. Does it help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS preflight request returning HTTP 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409105/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-405)

Comment: what is the content of the Allow header of that response?

Comment: @ArthurCantarela: So is there issue with the server side implementation? Because it is working fine in older versions of safari and postman also.

Comment: @V-Xtreme: Yes, preflight is something that browsers, including Chrome, do to prevent request of cross-site origin. When preflight returns 405, Chrome does not complete request. Postman works other way, there's no preflight (unless some configuration allows that option, idk). I don't know about Safari but I think the ideia is the same.

Comment: Did I help you?